# android json exception typeMismatch

Tags: android, json

my app was working really nice with that json

```
{
"id":"1",
"title_en":"Civil War",
"artist_en":"MOTORHEAD"
}
```

but when i tried to add multiple songs like that

```
{
"song_list":[
    {"id":"1",
    "title_en":"Civil War",
    "artist_en":"MOTORHEAD"},
    {"id":"2",
    "title_en":"Slide It In",
    "artist_en":"WHITESNAKE"}]
}
```

it generates an exception, even before retrieving data

```
09-08 07:29:53.998: W/System.err(982): org.json.JSONException: Value ? of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
09-08 07:29:53.998: W/System.err(982):  at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:107)
09-08 07:29:53.998: W/System.err(982):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
09-08 07:29:53.998: W/System.err(982):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
09-08 07:29:53.998: W/System.err(982):  at com.dwaik.jsonparser.JSONParser.getJSONObject(JSONParser.java:46)
09-08 07:29:53.998: W/System.err(982):  at com.dwaik.myapp.CustomizedListView.onCreate(CustomizedListView.java:48)
```

additional info : the parser

```
public JSONObject getJSONObject(InputStream inputStream)
{
    String result = null;
    JSONObject jObject = null;
    try
    {
        // json is UTF-8 by default
        BufferedReader reader;
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            sb.append(line + "\n");

        result = sb.toString();
        jObject = new JSONObject(result);
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            if (inputStream != null)
                inputStream.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
    return jObject;
}
```

and its call

```
final JSONObject jObject = (new JSONParser(this)).getJSONObject(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.sample));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a quick glance, you are trying to convert the entire string into a JsonObject, however, it is not a JsonObject, it's actualy a JsonArray containing multiple JsonObject's.

here's a small code snippet to guide you through a similar process of parsing a json string containing an array of json's :

```
public ArrayList<Ride> parse (String str) throws JSONException 
{ 
    ArrayList<Ride> rides = new ArrayList<Ride>(); 


    try{ 
        JSONArray ridesJsonArray = new JSONArray(str); 

        Ride ride; 
        for (int i=0;i<ridesJsonArray.length();i++) 
        { 
            ride = new Ride(); 
            JSONObject o = ridesJsonArray.optJSONObject(i); 
            ride.rideId=o.optInt("id"); 
            ride.fullName=o.optString("fullname"); 
            ride.origin=o.optString("origin");               
            ride.destination=o.optString("destination"); 
            ride.date=o.optString("date"); 
            ride.time=o.optString("time"); 
            ride.phone=o.optString("phone"); 
            ride.email=o.optString("email"); 
            ride.comments=o.optString("comments"); 

            //log message to make sure the rides are coming from the server 
            Log.i("Rides", ride.fullName + " | "); 

            rides.add(ride);             
        } 
        return rides; 
        }                                                
    catch (Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
        return null; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: doesnt the JSON root element here represent an object and has an array inside it? excuse me i am new to JSON

Comment: @Warlock `{` represents a json object node. `[` represetns a json array node. What you are getting is a string not an json object. hence the error. check your json data that is sent.

Comment: i have spotted the problem using json validator http://jsonlint.com/ there were some "و" instead of ","... keyboard language switch :)